# UVB sensing with Arduino

Tags: sensors, components

As part of the research I am involved with, the detection (not imaging) of UV (ultraviolet) sources, either emitters or reflectors is an important factor.

I am aware of the [SparkFun UV Sensor Breakout - ML8511](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12705) component, which, according to the [product specifications](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/LightImaging/ML8511_3-8-13.pdf), has a decent broadband response across the UVA and UVB, with little amount of visible light.

Is there an Arduino component that only detects the UVB waveband (280nm to 320nm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SparkFun board you mentioned should detect UVB and UVA, but I guess, from your question, that you want one that cannot detect UVA.

Basically any device that has an I2C interface *should* work with an Arduino as long as you know how to interface with the device in the code.

If your intention is professional research, than a demo device such as the SparkFun may not fit your needs anyway as it will not be particularly accurate and is mainly intended as a little board to play about with on your Arduino and say "Hey, look, there's UV light there!"

The answer to your question is that the best place to look is above the consumer range, at some higher-end UV sensors that are not generally suitable for the little Arduino demos due to price, but may give you much more accurate readings and only sense the UVB waveband.